# How Would I Return Two Multiple Select Values In HTML?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, parsing

I have a mysql database table called "leads" with an id column, a name column, and an email column.  I currently have users selecting a lead from a multiple select box, which is returned as an array from an html `form` with `$_POST` method.  I have the value for the select box items as the email column, and what is shown to the user on the front end is the name column.  However, I want to be able to return two values, the email and the name, for later use.  I need to have the email value(s) able to be imploded with commas between them, so I can later send them emails using PHP's `mail` function.  However, when a user looks at sent emails, I want to show them the name value(s).  I have read that I can either parse the array, or use the id column set as the value, which seems more practical, however, I am not sure how I would go about this.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for any help!

****UPDATE****

**Basically, the users that log into the site have their own leads in a mysql database.  I need them to be able to go to a 'send email' page, where they can select a lead, or multiple leads, by name.  Then there is a subject field, and a message field so they can write the email, and then I have a 'send email' form submit button.  After they click 'send email' I want to get back the email addresses and names of the leads they selected, for later use.  I need to have the email addresses separated by commas, so that I can send them through a php mail function...  But the important thing is, I want the info from the form to be stored in a database table called 'PendingEmails', and I am going to run a cron job to run a script that finds what emails need to be sent, and sends them...  After an email is sent, I need to put the names, subject, and message from the email in a separate database, called 'SentEmails'.  On a different page on the site, I want the users to be able to see all the emails they sent, but I want them to see the names of who they sent it to, rather than the email addresses.  This is why I need both the names and the emails.  I need emails for the mail function, and names to be displayed back to the user.  I like your idea of using the id and running the rest server side, I just dont know how I would do this.  Hope this helped.**

**Here is the select box:**

```
<select data-placeholder="Select Lead(s) To Email..." multiple="true" class="chzn-container-multi" name="selectleads[]"style="width:505px;">
            <?php
do {  
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_rsAllLeads['Email']?>"><?php echo $row_rsAllLeads['FullName']?></option>
            <?php
} while ($row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsAllLeads);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($rsAllLeads, 0);
      $row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads);
  }
?>
          </select>
```

**And here is the actual form action:**

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
    $startcode = $_POST['messagefield'];
    $replaced = preg_replace( '/\\\\(?="|\')/', '', $startcode );
    $selected = $_POST['selectleads'];
    $collectedleads = implode(", ", $_POST['selectleads']);
 $to = $collectedleads;
 $subject = $_POST['subjectfield'];
 $body = $replaced;
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "From: " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['FirstName'] . " " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['LastName'] . " <" . $row_rs_CurrentUser['Email'] . ">";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }

}
```

**The code you gave me and I tried (and failed) to edit and make work:**

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
    $startcode = $_POST['messagefield'];
    $replaced = preg_replace( '/\\\\(?="|\')/', '', $startcode );

    mysql_select_db($database_myBackOfficeConn, $myBackOfficeConn);

    $collectedleads = implode(", ", $_POST['selectleads']);

//arrays to store email addresses and names
$emails = array();
$names = array();

foreach ($collectedleads as $id) {
  mysql_query("SELECT Email, FullName FROM Leads 
    WHERE Id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($id));

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
    $emails[] = $row['Email'];
    $names[] = $row['FullName'];
  }
}
 $to = $collectedleads;
 $subject = $_POST['subjectfield'];
 $body = $replaced;
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "From: " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['FirstName'] . " " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['LastName'] . " <" . $row_rs_CurrentUser['Email'] . ">";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted... I think I know what you're talking about, but could you post a little code? Makes it easier to talk specifics.

Comment: Sure thing, and I feel the same way!  Why are people taking my rep away LOL!

Comment: Did the code I posted help any?

Comment: Just to check - you want the email list for a user to be displayed in a `<select>`. The user selects an option, clicks a button, and that email is displayed? Is that the deal?

Comment: No, I have the *Names* of the leads displayed in a select, and when a user selects one, the names and emails of who they selected will be sent to a mysql database, along with the subject and message...  Then, I will use a cron job to call a php script that will send an email to the provided email, with the corresponding subject and message.  Then, the names, subject, and message will be sent to a separate mysql database table called sentemails and I will have a separate webpage where they can view the sent emails, but I want them to be able to see the names of the leads, not the emails...

Comment: The only reason I have echo turned on is for testing purposes, and nothing is showing up :(

Comment: Did you see my comment below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would make more sense to do the retrieving of data on the server-side. Instead of the email addresses, set the `<option>` values to your database's `id` column values.

**EDIT: Changed most of the answer after discussing with OP**

Bearing in mind that the code you posted was just a snippet, and so I have no way of testing this, you could try something along these lines:

```
<select data-placeholder="Select Lead(s) To Email..." multiple="true" 
  class="chzn-container-multi" name="selectleads[]"style="width:505px;">
<?php   
  /* I think while is better, in case there are no results. 
    do...while would attempt to echo the first result in a set even 
    if there were no results, which would give an error, methinks. */

  //Use the id field of your database when you populate the select
  while ($row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads)) {  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row_rsAllLeads['id']?>">
    <?php echo $row_rsAllLeads['FullName']?></option>
<?php
  }

  /* What is this block used for? */
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsAllLeads);
  if($rows > 0) {
    mysql_data_seek($rsAllLeads, 0);
    $row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads);
  }
?>
</select>
```

I'm uncertain as to the purpose of the code block at the end so I just left it. I assume you do something else with that data...?

So now your `<select>` is exactly the same as before, but instead of actual email addresses it will hand back the corresponding database `id`s instead.

Now, on submitting the data, we change our tack slightly:

```
<?php
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
  $startcode = $_POST['messagefield'];
  $replaced = preg_replace( '/\\\\(?="|\')/', '', $startcode );
  $selected = $_POST['selectleads'];

  /* NEW CODE */
  /*selectleads[] is now an array of your database's ids. 
    You can now run a query to get whatever information you 
    need. In this case, you want the email addresses, so:
   */
  $collectedleads = $_POST['selectleads'];
  $emailaddylist = array();
  foreach ($collectedleads as $id) {
    $x = mysql_query("SELECT `Email` FROM `leads` WHERE `id` = " . 
       mysql_real_escape_string($id));
    $x_assoc = $x->fetch_assoc();
    $emailaddylist[] = $x['Email'];
  }
  /*Now you have an array of email addresses that correspond to 
    the ids you were sent via $_POST.
   */
  $emailaddystring = implode(", ", $emailaddylist);

  $to = $emailaddystring;

  /*If you want to use any other data from the database, 
     you still have an array of ids in $collectedleads.
     Just run another query to get the data you want.*/

  /* END OF NEW CODE */

  $subject = $_POST['subjectfield'];
  $body = $replaced;
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
  $headers .= "From: " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['FirstName'] . " " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['LastName'] . " <" . $row_rs_CurrentUser['Email'] . ">";
  if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    } else {
      echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
    }
}
?>
```

Because we are handed the `id`s in an array, we can use them to get whatever information we want from the database. In this case we're just getting the email addresses. If you want to retrieve any other information, you can use the same technique - the list of `id`s still exists in `$collectedleads`, so you can run another query to get whatever data you need.

> After an email is sent, I need to put the names, subject, and message
>   from the email in a separate database, called 'SentEmails'

In that case, use the `id` data in `$collectedleads` to run a `SELECT` query on `leads` to get the information you need (name, email address, whatever), and run an `INSERT` query on the `SentEmails` table to copy that information.

Hope this helps.

***CAVEAT:***

The use of `mysql` is discouraged in favour of [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php). To quote the page:

> If you are using MySQL versions 4.1.3 or later it is **strongly**
>   recommended that you use the mysqli extension instead.

It works almost exactly the same; in most cases all you need to do is to put the `i` in front of it. [Some functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) don't work with it, or have better alternatives. You should check it out.

Comment: Everything makes sense except fetch_assoc...  How would I use that?

Comment: I want to have one page where the users can view all of the emails they have sent through the site, and I want them to be able to see who they sent it to, the subject, and the message...  Where they see who they sent it to, I think it would be easier for them to see the names of the people they emailed, rather than the emails.

Comment: But separately, I need the actual email adress values, so that the PHP mail function knows where to send the emails.

Comment: But in the select box on the send email page, what the user sees are the names of the people, not their emails...

Comment: Does this help you understand better?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I've been experiencing trouble with SO because of the hurricane thing. I'll try to post a response sometime later today... sorry for the wait.

Comment: Ok, sounds good...  Another thing, I tried putting in your code above, and it kept giving me errors, so I messed with it, and lol, still didnt work...  I am about to edit my original post so you can see the code i put in.

Comment: Okay well first, `$collectedleads` is an array, so if you assign it to `$to`, the mail won't be sent because it is not an email address. If you have any errors, posting the error code and text is helpful :-)

Comment: Ok, but I thought if you implode `$collectedleads` it will become a correctly formatted string?  Anyway, the error I was receiving was an invalid argument in the foreach loop...

Comment: If you implode it, it will, but you didn't do that in the example that used my code :-) Anyway, I don't think what I posted was remotely correct, given your latest reply. Try reformatting your question so it asks for what you want more clearly. Don't worry about deleting parts of it if it will make it clearer. I want to help but I'm really not able to picture what it is you are trying to do. Make it step-by-step and really simple (I'm not very bright :-p) For example, where do the values for the select come from originally? What data comes from where and where does it go to, and so on. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, I added a better description... hope it helped.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You there?  I updated the description under the **Update** section

Comment: Thank you. I actually wasn't here; I was asleep, since it was night time here... Anyway I'll try to get back to you sometime today.

Comment: I tried to use the code and echo `$emailaddystring` and got this `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/content/06/9464206/html/BackOffice/Send Email.php on line 123`

Comment: This is line 123: `$x_assoc = $x->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: That means the MySQL query failed. Check that you are querying tables that exist, that there are no errant apostrophes or backticks, etc. I can't really help you with that as I don't know anything about your tables and data structure. If you need help debugging a MySQL query, it's really another question....

Comment: Cool! Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, I would add a hidden field named something along the lines of "lead_name" and fill it with jQuery or just plain JS on an onblur event with the value of the selected lead.

```
$("#lead_name").val($("#lead option:selected").text());
```